Can't log in to Ubuntu Server 24.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 via SSH after apt update
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 that I am want to use as a headless music player (plexamp).  I just performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 Server on an SD via the raspberry pi imager program.  I was able to set up SSH log in via this with username and password, and logged in successfully after first boot.  I performed an apt update and upgrade, then reboot, and now I cannot log in, and get a "Connection Refused" on port 22 when trying.
Any was to recover from this without plugging in a monitor, or just re-flashing the SD card with another distro and starting again?
Thanks!

If "Connection Refused" is accurate, then plugging in a monitor will be the easiest way to troubleshoot the problem. Is it possible that the IP address changed when you rebooted? Perhaps the refusal is coming from a different machine that now occupies the address.

This helped me:
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf
change "PasswordAuthentication no" to "PasswordAuthentication yes"
"sudo systemctl restart ssh" or reboot the raspberry

It is possible that ssh not running. What I would do is booting the card on a monitored machine and
# systemctl status ssh

to get info and debug if necessary.
If ssh running, another way could be the /etc/ssh/sshd_config to control the login conditions (PermitRootLogin for exemple)
Last way is Pam

Jeff:
I have found my RPi’s sometimes don‘t boot properly following a reboot or shutdown -r now command: they will just stop.  A power boot seems to be the only way to correct.
One way around plugging in a monitor is to remote desktop in: Remmina works if the remote system uses X11 but also needs prior configuration on the remote unit.  TigerVNC works with Wayland and IIRC does not need prior remote configuration (been a while).

Thank you all for the responses. I think it was due to a bad SD card.
I took it out to reformat it and it was read only. It was a cheap PNY card and I've had this happen when they die before.

Please don't thank others in your answers. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum.
